# is there a way to have pipelinee both triggered and standalone?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to be able to create a pipeline that is part of a CI/CD process. however, i want to be able to also run it stand alone; say for testing, or i only need the function it provides and not the rest of the "chain".
I am doing this in classic ADO.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: A pipeline can always be manually run whenever you want it. However with the classic UI if you manually ran the CI pipeline it would still trigger the CD pipeline. If you was using yaml you could add a condition to not trigger the pipeline if the CI pipeline triggering it had a manual build reason. However this isn't possible in the classic UI. Its a faff but if you wanted to run the CI pipeline just for functionality without triggering the CD pipeline you would have to temporarily turn off the trigger in the release pipeline

Comment: Hi Moshe, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question

Comment: thank you for your reply. it answers my question. What i have done is create variables and based on the values, i disable the task steps that i do not want to run. i will add a pipeline starter that in the even i want to run the entire CI/CD it will update all the variables in the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to create a pipeline that is part of a CI/CD
> process. however, i want to be able to also run it stand alone

Yes, you can. Since you are using the classic DevOps pipeline, you just need to create a branch based on the previous branch, and then run the pipeline is ok.

**pre-pipeline settings:**

[image]

**following-pipeline settings:**

[image]

Comment: i think i understand this solution and it might work. thanks